# For R: How to exclude some data files based on file language

Tags: r

I'm rather new to R (and in law school so this is all very new to me), so apologies if this is poorly worded. 
I have a series of about 1500 documents that I am importing into R to categorize and analyze later. The first thing that I need to do is exclude all documents that are written in French, which are labelled with an "FR" in the title/doc.info. I was curious what kind of code I could use to exclude that before importing the files to have a clean data set before analyzing anything (since it will obvious make a mess of processes like sentiment analysis). 
Any help is appreciated (even if that help is explaining how to better talk about coding). 
Kind regards!

edit 1
The code that I am using is readtext(folder), which you can see below:
    folder<-"C:/[pathway]"
    submissions<-readtext(folder)

```
submissions_text<-submissions$text

submission_number<- numeric()
submission_person<- factor()
submission_code<- factor()
submission_language<-factor()
submission_location<-factor()

for (submission_name in submissions$doc_id) {
  submission_name<-gsub(".txt","",submission_name)
  number<-as.numeric(strsplit(submission_name, "_|-")[[1]][1])
  submission_number<-c(submission_number,number)
  person<-strsplit(submission_name, "_")[[1]][2]
  submission_person<-c(submission_person, person)
  code<-strsplit(submission_name, "_")[[1]][3]
  submission_code<-c(submission_code, code)
  lang<-strsplit(submission_name, "_")[[1]][4]
  submission_language<-c(submission_language, lang)
  location<-strsplit(submission_name, "_")[[1]][5]
  submission_location<-c(submission_location, location)
}

submissions<-cbind(submissions,submission_number)
submissions<-cbind(submissions,submission_person)
submissions<-cbind(submissions,submission_code)
submissions<-cbind(submissions,submission_language)
submissions<-cbind(submissions,submission_location)


submissions<-submissions[order(submissions$submission_number, decreasing = FALSE),]
```

This is just the organizational aspect of my code. I am looking to hopefully exclude all of the French data before this point (but if it comes afterward, I would also be more than happy with that).

Comment: This is a really broad question - probably too broad to be easily answerable here. Have you taken attempts to write any code, for example just to import all  your documents? SO is not a code-writing service, so it's better to show some attempt (even if you're not confident in it) and then people can point you in better directions.

Comment: Sure. I can show you what I currently have.
folder<-"C:/[path]"
submissions<-readtext(folder)

submissions<-mutate(submissions, order = 1:182)
submissions<-submissions %>% select(order, doc_id:text)

#This will be for the first number, the ordering 
submission_number<- numeric()
submission_person<- factor()
submission_code<- factor()
submission_language<-factor()
submission_location<-factor()

for (submission_name in submissions$doc_id) {
  submission_name<-gsub(".txt","",submission_name)

[...] it goes on but my character count is too long.

Comment: You can put this as an edit into your question, so that others can give your code a try (though it looks like you've got a good answer already!). Keep it mind that you'll get better help if you include a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: My bad. Again, all new to me. Thanks for the patience!

Answer (score 4):

The functionality you are after can be found in the `list.files()` function. Documentation can be found [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.5.2/topics/list.files).

In short, your code will likely end up looking something like this:

```
setwd("c:/path/to/your/data/here")
files <- list.files()
non_french_files <- files[!grepl("FR", files)]
lapply(non_french_files, function(x) {
  f <- read.csv(x)
  #do stuff with f
}]
```

Note - you could directly leverage the `pattern` parameter found in `list.files(), but I chose to do that in two steps in case you wanted to do something else with the French files. This also simplifies what each line of code is doing...

...good luck and welcome to R!

Comment: Thanks! I am going to give this a try. I have been using readtext so far (probably should have mentioned that, sorry), but I will try this list.files. Thanks again!

Comment: You can also specify a regex pattern in `list.files()` and potentially skip have to assign `non_french_files()`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative similar to @Chase 's:

```
#set wd
files<-list.files()[!grepl("FR",list.files())]
lapply(files,function(x) read.csv(x)) #reads all at once, might want to save each
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, you guys have been great!